# Combining C-code files into one C-code file

Tags: android, c, c-preprocessor, renderscript

I'm converting libx264 to renderscript as an exercise in how much work it is to port a bit larger project into renderscript. One of the pains with renderscript is that everything needs to be declared static to not be automatically getting a java interface. Also this automatic java interface can't handle pointer, multi-dim arrays etc. Hence I need to declare all functions and global variables as static in libx264, besides a few invocation functions to control it.

My problem then is that since everything is declared static I need to have all the code in one file scope. I started to just include all the C-code files into one and compile that. Which would had worked quite easily if not libx264 itself had also included C-files with different pre-processing macro definitions, hence some functions exist twice with different content and some is redeclared identical. I could of course handle this manually, but it would be easier with a tool.

I'm asking if anyone knows of a tool that can take a **C** project and pre-process/merge that into one C-file, managing re-declarations, conflicting declarations, etc.

And I thought the heap allocations would be the difficult problem...

Comment: "My problem then is that since everything is declared static" - renderscript only supports a single C file per script anyway - there's no way to link multiple files together directly. Although you can call to another script via rsForEach.

Comment: Yes thanks, I discovered that after I posted, I did not test this first because there is support for .rsh files and I assumed that it allowed function declarations as the builtin .rsh files. But still I need a tool to merge all the c-files into one file properly. Since then this would be the only way of converting a general c project into renderscript.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tool that does this, CIL. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cil
http://kerneis.github.com/cil/doc/html/cil/merger.html

/Harald